# Adding cookies with Dart server?

Tags: dart, dart-io

So I have a simple HttpServer like this:

```
import 'dart:io';
main() {
    HttpServer
        .bind("127.0.0.1", 80)
        .then((server) {
            server.listen((request) {             
                // Add cookie here how?                
                request.response.write("Howdy Darty cowboy!");
                request.response.close();
            });
        });    
}
```

Is there a way to add cookies to the HttpResponse in Dart? 
I can see both `HttpResponse` and `HttpRequest` classes have `cookies` properties and I can access them, but I can't seem to figure out how to add a cookie.

Tried this:

```
request.response.cookies = ["name", "value"];
```

But got this error:

```
Error: The setter 'cookies' isn't defined for the class 'HttpResponse'.
```

So there are no predefined methods to work with cookies? 
Do I have to add my own HTTP Headers to add cookies?
Again, I can see headers properties in both classes, but no setters or getters!

Just started playing around with Dart.

Note: Please don't link me external packages, I would like to do it with Dart's core libraries. Don't want to get into another npm hell! Moved away from Node.js cause of `npm`, but looks like `pub` is identical, just uses yaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.response.cookies` is a `List<Cookie>`, so you'll want to `add` to it (rather than assign it with equals).

Try:

```
request.response.cookies.add(Cookie('name', 'value'));
```

Comment: Thanks @Richard! Yeah, its intuitive, <Cookie> is a List, and List has add method! Still wrapping my head around Dart, looks really good for now! Thanks again!